# How to get the today on contract generators count of id using range of start date and end date in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to get `count` of today `on-contracted generators`. I used where condition for **start date** and **end date** with today date, So i get count of on-contract generators when reaching start date and end date to **today date**. But I need to get count of on-contract generators when today date *between start date and end date.*

**Example**:- `Generator booked from RA_start date: 06-09-2018 to RA_end date: 08-09-2018`, I want to get the count of on-contract generators even when reach date to *07-09-2018*. now i am getting count only *RA_start date: 06-09-2018* and *RA_end date: 08-09-2018*.

Thank you

**My Model**

```
public function getToday_OncontractGenerator_count(){

            $today = date('Y-m-d');
            $this->db-> select('count(generator_id)as total_count');
            $this->db->from('generators');
            $this->db->join('rental_agreement','generator_id =generator_id_fk');
            $this->db->where('Rental_status',1);
            $this->db->where("RA_start_date", $today);
            $this->db->or_where("RA_end_date", $today);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this tweak :-

```
$today=date('Y-m-d');
$between="'$today' between RA_start_date and RA_end_date";
$this->db-> select('count(generator_id)as total_count');
$this->db->from('generators');
$this->db->join('rental_agreement','generator_id =generator_id_fk');
$this->db->where('Rental_status',1);
$this->db->where($between);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: I got syntax error because used square bracket, but i got correct result after removed it, thank you so much